# How to center tabs in MaterialTopTabNavigator in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I added `tabStyle: { width: "auto" }` to fit the tabs of MaterialTopTabNavigator to the width of the text, but by adding this, the tabs are moved to the left side as shown in the image below.

[Tabs are too far to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90IxV.jpg)

The answer to this question says to remove tabStyle, but if I remove tabStyle, all tabs will have the same width.

I thought about using my own component in the tabBar, but I gave up because I couldn't reproduce the animation when moving the tab.

I thought about using paddingHorizontal to force it to be centered, but I decided against it because it might not be centered if the font size is changed in the OS.

If you know more about this, please let me know how to solve it.

[The design I want to implement (edited in Paint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKhFH.jpg)

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";


const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const Page = () => {
  return (
        <Tab.Navigator
          tabBarOptions={{
            labelStyle: {
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
            activeTintColor: "#ffffff",
            inactiveTintColor: "#000000",
            pressOpacity: 1,
            indicatorStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "black",
              height: 30,
              borderRadius: 30,
              top: 9,
            },
            tabStyle: {
              width: "auto",
            },
          }}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Message" component={Message} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Store" component={Store} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};


export default Page;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should definitely work. If not, let me know.

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";


const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const Page = () => {
  return (
        <Tab.Navigator
          tabBarOptions={{
            labelStyle: {
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
            activeTintColor: "#ffffff",
            inactiveTintColor: "#000000",
            pressOpacity: 1,
            indicatorStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "black",
              height: 30,
              borderRadius: 30,
              top: 9,
            },
            tabStyle: {
              width: "auto",
            },
          }}
        >
          <View style={{flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"center"}}>
          <View>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Message" component={Message} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Store" component={Store} />
          </View>
          </View>

          // If the above does not work than use the below one and comment the above part
          
        //  <View style={{flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"center"}}>
        //  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        //  <Tab.Screen name="Message" component={Message} />
        //  <Tab.Screen name="Store" component={Store} />
        //  </View>

        </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried it, but got the error ``a navigator can only contain 'screen' 'group' or 'react.fragment'... ``

Answer (score 1):

Just apply those styles to `screenOptions` parameter in your navigator and you're done:

```
tabBarStyle: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  tabBarItemStyle: {
    width: "auto",
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `tabBarContentContainerStyle` attribute below, it works well for me：

```js
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Attention"
      screenOptions={{
        lazy: true,
        tabBarPressOpacity: 1,
        tabBarPressColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: Style.unActiveText,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Style.mainColor,
        tabBarContentContainerStyle: {
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
          display: 'none',
        },
        tabBarItemStyle: {
          width: 70,
          paddingHorizontal: 0,
          position: 'relative',
          padding: 0,
          height: 45,
        },
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          fontSize: 15,
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          width: 'auto',
          height: 45,
          borderBottomColor: 'red',
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
        },
      }}>
      </Tab.Navigator>
```